Why is `.pipe` undefined on `combineLatest` of BehaviourSubjects?
In an Angular 10 app I have a service class:
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private readonly bSubject1$: BehaviorSubject<SomeType[]> = new BehaviorSubject<SomeType[]>(null);
  private readonly bSubject2$: BehaviorSubject<AnotherType[]> = new BehaviorSubject<AnotherType[]>(null);
  private readonly bSubject3$: BehaviorSubject<LastType[]> = new BehaviorSubject<LastType[]>(null);
  
  private readonly subscription$: Observable<SomeType[]>;
  private readonly bs4$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  private readonly bs5$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(router: Router) {
    this.subscription$ = this.createStructure();

    router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        console.log('some code here');
      });
  }

  private createStructure() {
    const sub$ = combineLatest([this.bSubject1$, this.bSubject2$, this.bSubject3$])
      .pipe(filter(...), map(...));

    return combineLatest([sub$, this.bs4$, this.bs5$])
      .pipe(map(...));
  }

}

Which I'm trying to test like this:
export class RouterMock {}

describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useClass: RouterMock },
        { provide: MyService, useClass: service },
      ],
    });

    service = TestBed.inject(MyService);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    console.log('service', service);  // service is logged as `undefined`
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

});

And the test fails on the line private createStructure() {, with Failed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe').
What am I missing in the test mock?
Edit: here is a stackblitz with matched package versions, reproducing the issue.

Shouldn't the providers array be just [Dep1Service, MyService]?

@Cuzy if I were to give only the names of the services, they/some would fail with Failed: R3InjectorError ... NullInjectorError: No provider for Dep1Service!

After matching all package versions and reproducing the issue in stackblitz, I noticed that the line number for the error was mentioning a different statement.
The local code mentions the line with private createStructure() {, so I suspected the pipe which followed had the issue;
While stackblitz mentions line with .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
So from there it was easy to conclude that the Router mock was missing an events property, to make the test pass.
export class RouterMock {
  events = of([]); // <- the fix
}

Thank you to @Naren Murali for suggesting the providers update and reproducing the issue in stackblitz. Those actions ended a day of trials and errors.

Try to give a mock service imports (Dep1Service) and provide the proper service for My Service
export class Dep1ServiceMock {}

describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: Dep1Service, useClass: Dep1ServiceMock },
        MyService,
      ],
    });

    service = TestBed.inject(MyService);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    console.log('service', service);  // service is logged as `undefined`
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

});


I have updated the providers to use mock classes (and mocked the required methods when needed), for all the dependencies (represented here by just Dep1Service), but the test fails with the same error, in the same place.

@Andrei try Testbed.get( also please replicate the issue in this stackblitz and share back!

with .get, I see it displays it crossed, and seems to make no difference. I've added the code in this stackblitz, but I see it's displaying a different error here, maybe because of the version differences.
